# How can I avoid getActivity() == null in onServiceConnected inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I bind a Service inside a Fragment using:

```
private ServiceConnection mConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
       //HOW CAN I AVOID THIS BEING NULL???
       if(getActivity() == null)
         System.out.println("NOT HAPPY:(((");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can't guarantee it won't be `null`. If the fragment is detached from the activity before `onServiceConnected()` is called, `getActivity()` will return `null`. Detachment could occur due to configuration changes, activity destruction, or specific fragment transactions. You might want to reconsider whether binding to the service is really necessary or the right solution.

Comment: why can't you write your `onServiceConnected` code inside the `onActivityCreated `? `onActivityCreated` is Called when the fragment's activity has been created, and hence `getActivity()` will not be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

That meanse that your code is called before the fragment is attached
Try this:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }
```

Comment: There is no value, and definite potential cost (in the form of potential memory leaks), in holding onto the activity in a data member this way, depending on how the rest of the fragment is set up.

Comment: Ok, but what about the statement that fragments always keeps its parent activity's reference and makes you available through getActivity() method? Here we are keeping that reference. Nothing more. Also, Google recommends this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html ,,Creating event callbacks to the activity" (i have found this on SO a few months ago, when i had similar problem).

Comment: "Here we are keeping that reference. Nothing more" -- except that you do not show setting `mActivity` to `null` in `onDetach()`. If you do not do that, you introduce a possible memory leak, particularly in a retained fragment. And if you do set it to `null` in `onDetach()`, then you are duplicating `getActivity()` and have wasted ~4 bytes of heap and several lines of code for no added value.

Comment: "Google recommends this" -- in their case, they are not just holding onto the activity, but are casting it to an interface, which adds incremental value. However, they too screw up and do not show `onDetach()` and releasing their reference, so I'll file a bug report for that. Regardless, none of this addresses the OP's problem, because if `getActivity()` returns `null`, `mActivity` had better also be `null`, or you messed up.

Comment: Ok, however i have not seen any special solution to this problem. If all given solutions have some important flaws, then in order to implement this functionality, you need to find a workaround, or to change the whole concept.

Comment: And I would vote for "change the whole concept". I am not a fan of bound services, as it introduces too much state and tight coupling. I'd rather set up event-driven communications through an event bus.

Comment: I agree with you, onServiceConnected is called with a significant delay, and can cause big problems.  Thank you for these clarifications.

Comment: @CommonsWare Broadcast receivers are my event bus. That said, I simply tolerate non-deterministic failure. Sad, it sucks :(

Answer (score 0):

I do like this...
In Application class i used to write this getter and setter for getting activity context,

```
private static Context mContext;

public static Context getCurrentActivityContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public static void setCurrentACtivityContext(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

And i will call the setter from all activities onCreate(), onResume(), onStart().
I will call the getter from fragments to get the context object.
I can say this will help you in your case, you will not get any NPE's.